# Checking Admins who are MFA enabled using Strong Authentication Methods

Tags: powershell

There is an upcoming audit of our institution and I just need to verify this script.
because our system admins are saying they are MFA enabled but when I run the script it displays that they are not. So upon further checking they might be enabled using StrongAuthenticationRequirements not through Strong Authentication methods as per the the script or code. Please clarify or enlighten me as I am not a pro when it comes to powershell.

```
Function Get-O365AdminMFAStatus{
    $AdminData=@()
    $objRole=@()
    $Domain = $(get-addomain).dnsroot
    $Log = "C:\temp\Audit\$Domain O365 Admin MFA Status $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"

try{
    $Roles = Get-MsolRole | where {$_.name -LIKE "*Administrator*"}
    $Roles = ($Roles).name

    foreach ($Role in $Roles){
        $Members = Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId (Get-MsolRole -RoleName $Role).ObjectId 
        foreach ($Member in $Members){
            $MsUser = $Member | Get-MsolUser
            if($MsUser.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count -eq 0) {
                $Enabled = "False"
                write-host $Role - $Member.DisplayName "No MFA enabled" -foregroundcolor red
            }
            Else{
                $Enabled = "True"
                write-host $Role - $Member.DisplayName "MFA enabled" -foregroundcolor green
            }   

            Try{
                $Exist = [bool](Get-mailbox $MsUser.UserPrincipalName -erroraction SilentlyContinue)
                if ($Exist){
                    $MBStats = Get-MailboxStatistics $MsUser.UserPrincipalName
                    $LastLogon = $MBstats.LastLogonTime
                }
                Else{
                    $LastLogon = "N/A"
                }
            }
            Catch{
                $LastLogon = "N/A"
            }

            $objRole = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $objRole | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Role Name" -Value $Role
            $objRole | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Display Name" -Value $Member.DisplayName
            $objRole | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UPN" -Value $Member.UserPrincipalName
            $objRole | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Licensed" -Value $Member.IsLicensed
            $objRole | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Last Logon" -Value $LastLogon
            $objRole | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MFA Enabled?" -Value $Enabled

            $AdminData += $objRole
        }
    }

    $AdminData | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $Log 
    write-host ""
    write-host "CSV Export Complete to $Log" -foregroundcolor yellow
}
Catch{
    Write-host "There was an error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

}

```
Get-O365AdminMFAStatus
```

what does eq-0 mean `($MsUser.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count -eq 0)`

Answer (score 0):

`-eq` is one of the Comparison Operators in PowerShell that stands for Equal. In this case it means:

*If ($MsUser.StrongAuth...... is empty*)

e.g. *If there are no StrongAuthenticationMethods, then{ do something }*
There are many Comparison Operators.

Take a look at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1][1]